# Getting Null Values while reading Values into a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I am trying to read a `.csv` file into a Python dataframe but it is showing null values.

The `.csv` file has columns separated by `;`.

I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd    
data = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv', sep = ';')
```

and this is the output:

[image]

All values are null and number of rows got doubled

Comment: Open up the csv in a text editor (like notepad++) and see what it looks like

Comment: updated in orignal question

Comment: data= pd.read_csv('testfile.csv' , sep = ';', encoding = 'UTF-16')

it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv', sep = ';' , encoding = 'UTF-16')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).